# How to write success and error functions in angular 6

Tags: angular6

How to write success and error functions in angular 6

i have tried this

```
.success(data =>
{

})

.error(data =>
{

})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is better:

```
               .subscribe(data =>{
                    console.log(data);
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear but I am assuming that you are asking about observables.
This can be done in following manner:

```
myObservable.subscribe(
  x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
);
```